# How to use the element plus UI library with nuxt 3 setup?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to use the element plus UI library with the nuxt 3 setup. Need help on setup nuxt.config.ts file for element plus module

https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus-nuxt-starter/blob/main/nuxt.config.ts

I have tried the above things but it seems it is the old syntaxt or something wrong and not working.

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-table-column
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-table
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-button


import { ElTable, ElTableColumn, ElButton } from "element-plus/dist/index.full.js";
```

I have used the el plus table and table columns and button element but it returns this warning in the console. If I used to import (as mentioned above) each component then it works fine but I need to import the main el plus element globally.

I have installed the element plus as per the element installation guide for vue 3 and I am facing this issue in nuxt 3

Comment: Got any errors in the console? What is not working exactly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community
I Edited the code and commented. Please check and help in whatever you can.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @kissu
I Edited the code and commented. Please check and help in whatever you can.
Thanks in advance